# Angular 2 get the value of a single entry in a JSON array

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

like the title says, I am trying to get some values of an JSON array which only holds one object. I need to parse everything inside the component to work with the values. I finally need the values of TAG, NAME and COMM.

Here was the start situation. I had this:

```
{ "site": "Dimension", "data": [ { "TAG": "DimTime", "NAME": "Zeit", "COMM": "Zeitdimension", "$$index": 1 } ] }
```

Afterwards I break down the object by using:

```
currentObject['data']
```

and I got:

```
[ { "TAG": "DimTime", "NAME": "Zeit", "COMM": "Zeitdimension", "$$index": 1 } ]
```

but I am trying to find a solution to get the values of TAG, NAME and COMM now. The problem is that I always have a single object inside the json array "data". Or maybe a possibility to remove the outer brackets?

Do you guys have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you needed the values TAG, NAME and COMM, and you weren't sure how to do that, convert your data as an object or keep the array. Well, it's really up to you :) But let's take your example data and give you both options:

"array-option":

```
currentObject['data'] = [{"TAG":"DimTime","NAME":"Zeit","COMM":"Zeitdimension","$$index":1} ]
```

in your view you can then output your values with the first object (your only object) in your array.

```
{{currentObject['data'][0].TAG}} 
{{currentObject['data'][0].NAME}} 
{{currentObject['data'][0].COMM}}
```

If you want to convert your data to an Object, that's fine too, you can use Object.assign. This at least makes your code a bit shorter ;)

```
dataObj = Object.assign({}, currentObject['data'][0]);
```

and then in your view you can display:

```
{{dataObj.TAG}} 
{{dataObj.NAME}} 
{{dataObj.COMM}}
```

If you like,

you can read more about Object.assign [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

### Working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/i9PJMW3x8rdBUjUxbBRN)

Comment: Hello Sir and many thx for the quick reply. I already tried something similar. Both of the posted methods are stopping my app working.

Comment: Hmm. What error are you getting? Would be glad to help. If possible, you could provide a small plunker :)

Comment: That's strange. The above should really work. Could you provide a plunker for me to look at?

Comment: you have declared your data and  used `this`, right? e.g `this.dataObj = Object.assign({}, this.currentObject['data'][0]`.

Comment: No, that is absolutely correct, just checking :) Best would definately be if you could reproduce the issue in a plunker. Plunker has templates for Angular 2, so you just need to add some of your code. Just enough so that problem can be reproduced. Otherwise there is not much else I can help with, based on the code you have provided.

Comment: I am using AngularCLI, so that could be really hard. Do you maybe have another idea for this?

Comment: Well all the better, if you try to reproduce it, and it works, then you know it's a AngularCLI issue ;) If it doesn't work, then I can take a look at it ;)

Comment: I added a working plunker with the data as you have presented. So error has to be somewhere else than you have provided. I cannot do more than this. If you do not wish to make a plunker, I cannot do much else.

Answer (score 2):

`currentObject['data']` is an array, you can access its elements by index: `currentObject['data'] [0]`

Comment: I already tried that. This is working fine console.log(this.currentObject['data']) and this stops my app to load console.log(this.currentObject['data'] [0]). First one prints this to console : http://www.pic-upload.de/view-32544238/test.jpg.html

Comment: without actual error message it is impossible to tell anything